# While loop for the script below

Tags: python, while-loop

I'm currently in the process of creating a game where it loops over and over again until you guess the right number.

The problem I'm having is getting the looping command right. I want to go for a while loop but I can get it to work, for certain parts of the script. If I use a "while true" loop, the if statement's print command is repeated over and over again  but if I use any symbols (<, >, <=, >= etc.) I  can't seem to get it to work on the elif statements. The code can be found below:

```
#GAME NUMBER 1: GUESS THE NUMBER
from random import randint
x = randint(1,100)
print(x) #This is just here for testing
name = str(input("Hello there, my name's Jarvis. What's your name?"))
print("Hello there ",name," good to see you!")
num = int(input("I'm thinking of a number between 1 and 100. can you guess which one it is?"))
attempt = 1
while  
    if num == x:
        print("Good job! it took you ",attempt," tries!")
        num + 1
    elif num >= x:
        print("Too high!")
        attempt = attempt + 1      
    elif num <= x:
        print("Too low!")
        attempt = attempt + 1
    else:
        print("ERROR MESSAGE!")
```

Any and all help is appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a boolean in the `while` :

```
from random import randint
x = randint(1,100)
print(x) #This is just here for testing
name = str(input("Hello there, my name's Jarvis. What's your name?"))
print("Hello there ",name," good to see you!")
attempt = 1
not_found = True
while not_found:
    num = int(input("I'm thinking of a number between 1 and 100. can you guess which one it is?"))
    if num == x:
        print("Good job! it took you ",attempt," tries!")
        not_found = False
    elif num > x: #Don't need the equals
        print("Too high!")
    elif num < x: #Don't need the equals
        print("Too low!")
    else:
        print("ERROR MESSAGE!")
    attempt = attempt + 1
```

Comment: I'll edit my answer, you need the input inside the while loop

Comment: Looks correct now (haven't tested). Stylistically, I think it's easier to reason about booleans if you don't negate what they stand for with the identifier. What I mean is, I would initialize `found = False` and do `while not found:`.

Answer (score 1):

Your while needs a colon, and a condition

```
 while True:
```

and if you use a while True:  you have to end the loop, you can use a variable for this.

```
while foo:
    #Your Code

    if num == x:
        foo = False
```

Also, you could use string format instead of breaking your string. For example,

```
print("Good job! it took you %s tries!" % attempt)
```

or

```
print("Good job! it took you {0} tries!".format(attempt))
```

Answer (score 1):

You should put your question in the loop, because you want to repeat asking after each failure to get it right. Then also `break` the loop when user found it:

```
attempt = 0
while True:  
    attempt = attempt + 1
    num = int(input("I'm thinking of a number between 1 and 100. can you guess which one it is?"))
    if num == x:
        print("Good job! it took you ",attempt," tries!")
        break
    elif num >= x:
        print("Too high!")
        attempt = attempt + 1      
    elif num <= x:
        print("Too low!")
    else:
        print("ERROR MESSAGE!")
```